# ServiceStack authentication with both [Authenticate] and [ValidateApiKey] attributes

Tags: authentication, servicestack, api-key

I have some endpoints decorated with the [Authenticate] attribute. Now a third party client has to access the same endpoint by using a shared API key. 
As the code would be exactly the same for the two cases, I would like to check first if the current request comes from an authenticated user and, if not, checks as fallback if a valid API key is provided.

Is there a way to use both **[Authenticate]** and **[ValidateApiKey]** attributes for the same endpoint?

Something like:

```
[Authenticate | ValidateApiKey]
public long Post(MyDto request)
{
   // ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes can only be combined to add functionality, i.e. they can't be used as a fallback or a switch. To get the desired behavior your `[ValidateApiKey]` attribute should perform the validation fallback as part of its implementation, e.g:

```
public class ValidateApiKeyAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object reqDto)
    {
        var session = req.GetSession();
        if (session == null || !session.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //If not a valid key, execute the `[Authenticate]` attribute 
            //to handle failed response
            if (!CheckValidApiKey(req))
                new AuthenticateAttribute().Execute(req,res,reqDto);
        }            
    }
}
```

> Note: Responses should be reference types (e.g. DTO's) or raw strings not value types.

```
public object Post(MyDto request)
{
   // ....
}
```

Comment: In our case, we ended up creating two endpoints in order to keep the authentication logic separated. But thanks for clarify!